# how to access the menu through keyboard shortcut

Tags: javascript, html

I need to access menu1 and menu2 using keyboard short cut

my code is here

```
  <ul>
        <li>Menu 1
            <ul>
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Menu 2
            <ul>
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

any one please help...

Comment: what have you tried.
simple search will tell you to use `keypress` `keyup` `keydown` events in jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Key events to achieve this

http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

You can also use `accesskey` attribute for anchor tag:

```
<a href="example.html" accesskey="s">example</a>
```

Refer

http://code.google.com/p/keyboard-accessible-jquery-menu/

[Keyboard friendly CSS menus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896787/keyboard-friendly-css-menus?lq=1)

[Keyboard accessible web dropdown menus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945490/keyboard-accessible-web-dropdown-menus?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Give it a tabindex and access using the Tab KeyStroke

```
<ul>
        <li tabindex="1">Menu 1
            <ul>
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li tabindex="2">Menu 2
            <ul>
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

And to access the LI using keyboard use this

```
onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == ${keycode}) document.getElementById('ID').click()
```